# How to remove a too large file in a commit when my branch is ahead of master by 5 commits

Tags: git

**Context**

I'm working alone on a project and I used github until now to save my work other than on my computer.
Unfortunately, I added a very large file to the local repository : 300mb (which exceed Github's limit).

**What I did**

I will try to make an history of what I made :

1. I (dumbly) added everything to the index :

   ```
    git add *
   ```
2. I committed changes :

   ```
    git commit -m "Blablabla"
   ```
3. I tried to push to origin master

   ```
    git push origin master
   ```

It took a while, so I just CTRL+C, and repeated step 2 and 3 four times, until I realised that a file was too large to be pushed to github.

4. I made the terrible mistake to delete my large file (I don't remember if I did a git rm or a simple rm)
5. I followed the instructions on (https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data)
6. When I try to git filter branch, I get the following error : "Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a development team with rewritten Git repo history, removing big files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444091/update-a-development-team-with-rewritten-git-repo-history-removing-big-files)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When you deleted your file, that will be a change and that is the unstaged change that git is complaining about.  If you do a git status you should see the file listed as removed/deleted.  To undo this change you should `git checkout -- <filename>`.  Then the file will be back and your branch should be clean.  You can also `git reset --hard` this will bring your repo back to the status where you made your commit.

I am assuming that it is the last commit that has the very large file that you want to remove.  You can do a `git reset HEAD~`  Then you can redo the commit (not adding the large file).  Then you should be able to `git push` without a problem.

Since the file is not in the last commit then you can do the final steps without a problem.  You just need to get your changes either committed or removed.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer ! Problem is, I deleted the large file not in the latest commit ... So when I issue a `git status` I do not see my large file in the list ...

Comment: The error that you are getting is because of modifications that are not commited so you will want to `git reset --hard` to get rid of these changes.

Comment: Ok ! I guess I should backup the work I made within these 5 commits ?
Do I just issue `git reset --hard`or do I use `git reset --hard origin master` ?

Comment: You don't need to backup anything within the 5 commits.  As long as you don't delete the repo that info is there.  Your problem is that you have files listed as being changed, that is what `git status` is showing you.  If you want to keep the files make another commit, if you don't need the changes then you can do `git reset --hard` this set the state of your repo to the latest commit that you have.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked !!!! Thank you so much ! I will vote for your answer as soon as I have enough reputation :) *

Answer (score 114):

## A simple solution I used:

1. Do **`git reset HEAD^`** for as many commits you want to undo, it will keep your changes and your actual state of your files, just flushing the commits of them.
2. Once the commits are undone, you can **then think about how to re-commit your files in a better way**, e.g.: removing/ignoring the huge files and then adding what you want and then committing again. Or use Git LFS to track those huge files.

---

**Edit**: this answer is also acceptable if for instance your commits needed authentication (e.g.: username and email) and that you need to add the proper credentials after having commited. You can undo things the same way.

**Question**: would someone have a way to just cherrypick the commit that is bad and change it directly? I'm asking especially in the case of someone who would just need to re-authenthify his commits like in [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git), but in a case where the files needs not to be changed. Only commits to authentify.

Comment: Nice - this is a very decent solution! For speed I recommend just adding large files to your .gitignore after a reset :)

Comment: use ~n insted of ^ where n is the number of commits you are ahead incase it is more than one commit. Also it seems git has problems recognizing ^ depending on the localization, for me, it doesnt work in a french command prompt, so when its 2 commits ahead, i had to use ~2.

Comment: This is a cool answer. The one thing I didn't understand was the use of `^` versus `~`. I found this post pretty helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git for anyone else who had similar questions.

Answer (score 20):

The github solution is pretty neat. I did a few commits before pushing, so it's harder to undo. Githubs solution is :
Removing the file added in an older commit

If the large file was added in an earlier commit, you will need to remove it from your repository history. The quickest way to do this is with The BFG (a faster, simpler alternative to git-filter-branch):

```
bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M
# Git history will be cleaned - files in your latest commit will *not* be touched
```

https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Answer (score 9):

This is in reference to the BFG post above, I would comment directly, but I have no idea how to do so as a low reputation new user.

You may want to do a 'git gc' to repack first.

I had issues getting BFG to work until I did so, this appears to be a common issue if you've only been working in a local repo and are prepping stuff to put up on a remote for the first time.

Relevant google hit which twigged me to it: https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/issues/65

Comment: I just had to do this (my .gitignore wasn't set up correctly) and bfg said this in the output for the original try:

`Warning : no large blobs matching criteria found in packfiles - does the repo need to be packed?`

That might be a new(er) thing since this question is quite old.

Answer (score 6):

I continue to run into this problem over and over again, and I don't seem to learn not to do it. The solutions offered here have worked for me before, but for some reason not this time, but here is what did work (from https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tutorial-removing-large-files-from-git-78dbf4cf83a):

to remove the large file

```
git rm --cached <filename>
```

Then, to edit the commit

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

Then you can push your amended commit with

```
git push
```

Comment: I've found this whole too large file issue to be confounding. Thanks for the solution. For me, the large size occurs from output embedded in jupyter notebooks. First the output has to be cleared before your commands. Don't be like me and forget to do a `git add <filename>` for each reduced size file before the `git push`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your only problem is having unstaged changes.  You didn't give any detail as to what was actually out of sync, so it's a shot in the dark, but assuming you simple-`rm`d the file in step 4, you'd bring it back from the index with:

```
git checkout large_file
```

If not, you're on your own.  Your goal is to make sure both your index and your working tree are in the same state.  This shows as `git status` reporting nothing to commit, working directory clean.

The nuclear option to ensure a clean tree would be `git reset --hard`.  If you want to try that, do backup your tree+repo beforehand.

Once your working copy is clean, you can proceed with your steps 5 and 6.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I `rm`d my large file and then committed 4 times ... The large file is not important to me. I just don't want it to upload to github.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Download and install BFG Repo-Cleaner (BFG), which is available [here](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). My download was `bfg-1.13.0.jar`.
2. A potentially helpful location to move the downloaded jar file, in my case `bfg-1.13.0.jar`, to is your ${JAVA_HOME}/lib. That is what I did because I want the `Java` specific libraries like these in a somewhat sensible location since they are not like ordinary Windows installations. You may wish to rename the jar file simply as `bfg.jar` to keep things simple - so below, where I use `bfg.jar`, I actually mean `bfg-1.13.0.jar` in my case.
3. Run `java -jar ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/bfg.jar --delete-files <file_name> --no-blob-protection .`; you should replace the whole of `<file_name>` with the specific file name that is causing the issue - note that the path to the file is not necessary ONLY the file name by itself.
4. Run `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` to complete the BFG cleaning job
5. Finally, run `git push origin main --force` to complete pushing any outstanding local commits as you desire.
6. If you have done everything up until this point successfully then your problem has been solved
7. Going forward, always check that you do not inadvertently add very large files in directories to Git if you wish to avoid this problem reoccurring.

Answer (score 1):

**Copy newest Repo state**

`cp -r original_repo repo_tmp`

**Reset Original Repo to state before large file was commited**

`cd original_repo && git reset --hard {commit_before_large_file}`

**Remove .git from repo_tmp, so we only get the contents**

`cd .. && rm -rf repo_tmp/.git`

Copy & Replace repo_tmp (newest repo state) to the original_repo folder

`cp -r repo_tmp original_repo`

**Now Add, Commit & Push and you are good to go**

`git add . && git commit -m "be gone large file" && git push`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove a file from an earlier commit, you can do `git rebase -i` (interactive), and `edit` the commit you need to change.

**OR**, you can create a new commit with all the changes you want (ie. remove the large file), then start `git rebase -i` and reorder commits, so that your "repair" commit is directly after the one where you committed the large file.
In the rebase script, replace `pick` with `squash`. That will merge two commits into one.

See [Git - Rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for details.